# Failing to ask for crypt password on boot forces emergancy boot

Tags: boot, encryption, thunderbird

I'm running Vivid on HP Pavilion 15.

**The Problem?**

When I boot the system, I get the purple screen that checks the disk. 
If I skip or wait till the end, I am pushed into emergency boot.
(it should be asking me for the password to mount the crypt swap but it is not.)

When in emergency boot, it allows me to press <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to get to the GUI (this is in a root terminal, without login) or it asks to run `systemctrl reboot` or default.

When I press <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> in the GUI most things work, but when I search unity *nothing shows up* and the system is noticeably slower. When I run commands in the terminal they just close immediately.

I think I now nave `initrd.img` and `initrd.img.old`

I think it may be something to do with this which is from `journalctl -b`

```
Device dev-disk-by\x2dpartlabel-Basic\x5cx20data\x5cx20partition.device appeared twice with different sysfs paths /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/h
```

**How the problem happened?**

I left the machine suspended and when I came back to it, `thunderbird` was not working so I rebooted and got this issue.

Hope someone can help, I have had a look around but can find anything related.